# How to create an organisation account on chrome web store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I have searched a lot about this on web but found nothing relevant. I want to publish chrome extension on web store on behalf of my organisation. My organisation uses Google apps. But I cant see any option to publish in chrome webs store even after logging into my organisation account on google. Please help

Answer (score 1):

May be you have googled with wrong set of token words. Please check the link below:
https://developers.google.com/chrome/web-store/docs/publish. Here you can get all the relevant information. A developer account is to be created. Then you can login to the developer dashboard and publish your app or extension. Still, if you find it difficult, please let me know.

Comment: I have the same problem. There is only option to publish the app as a developer, not as an organization.
The link you mentioned only show ways to publish the app targeting a domain, not to change the "author".

Comment: @romulof You said it right. There is no organisation specific registration. What we did was, to create a generic mail id for the purpose and register using that.